# How can I bind table-layout with array-list in android?

Tags: android, binding, android-layout, arraylist

Is there any way to bind a table-layout to array list in android, and how?

I mean like in C# that you type: table.datasource = list;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Table-layout, why don't you use listview? In listview, you can easily bind the data adapter to the listview.

I suggest if you can use ListView for your requirement then use it, its easy to implement as compared to TableLayout.

To set adapter inside the ListView, you just need to call:

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I need table layout because I need two columns and header for each of them. Can I do it with listview?